# find -exec с функцией в bash скрипте

Tags: linux, bash, shell

**Суть вопроса.**
Есть **bash**-скрипт в котором я объявил функцию **printtestpath**.

```
function printtestpath(){
echo "Im working $1"
}
```

по одиночке функция запускается прекрасно.

```
printtestpath "/test/path"
```

мне нужно чтобы параметр, который попадает в функцию брался из **find** на каждом этапе поиска файла.
Т.е. нашел 1 файл, запустил функцию 1 раз. Нашел ещё файл ещё раз запустил функцию.

```
find -type f -exec printtestpath {} \;
```

логичным выводом сделать для поиска атрибут -exec но входе этого появляется ошибка:

```
find: ‘printtestpath’: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

есть ли возможность это как-то исправить?

***ps.** Вывод из **find** в **файл**, а потом чтение из **файла** с запуском функции работает недостаточно быстро*

Comment: что-то из серии `find -type f | wile read f; do printtestpath "$f"; done` тоже не устроит? а обернуть `printtestpath` в скрипт?

Comment: @Fat-Zer 
1. В while пропущена буква h
2. Спасибо
3.Хотелось бы одним скриптом.

Comment: ну так можно свой же скрипт запускать, просто передать параметр дополнительный

Answer (score 1):

`find -type f -exec cmd args ...` внутри себя делает fork и порождает процесс с исполняемым файлом `cmd` и параметрами argv сконструированными из `args ...`

Функция `printtestpath` задана внутри bash и не является исполняемым файлом. Именно об этом вам сообщает find `‘printtestpath’: Нет такого файла или каталога`

**План А**: Вам нужно сделать бинарник или скрипт с именем `printtestpath`. Сразу скажу, что это будет сравнительно неторопливый вариант, так как отдельный процесс будет порождаться для каждого файла.

**План Б**: написать цикл, как предложил @Fat-Zer. Я бы делал именно так, если обработка одноразовая. Этот вариант довольно быстро работает, если в `printtestpath` не создаются процессы (то есть не запускаются программы).

**План В**: если вы боретесь за высокую скорость, то переписать скрипт на python. Что-нибудь вроде

```
import os
import os.path

def printtestpath(path):
    print(f"Im working {path}")

for subdir, _, subdir_files in os.walk('.'):
    for fname in subdir_files:
        fullname = os.path.join(subdir, fname)
        printtestpath(fullname)
```

Так как библиотеки Python позволяют очень многое без запуска внешних процессов, то в большинстве случаев сложная обработка файлов на Python будет быстрее, чем средствами bash и утилит. Я бы делал так, если бы нужен был скрипт, который будет исполняться в будущем много раз. Потерять некоторое время на разработку, зато сэкономить в будущем на запусках.

Comment: Судя по тестам скорость выполнения программ на питоне гораздо медленее чем например у C или Golang. Но сама идея заключается именно в баше, потому что в нем хочется разобраться.